# ruby array each_with_index

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration, command-line-arguments

In this code i want to iterate my array according to index value which is provided by code like one time i want to iterate and get output of ARGV[1] second time ARGV[3].

suppose

```
ARGV = ["-f","abc","-x","-p","wer"]

#!/usr/bin/env ruby

@lenght = ARGV.length
@factory_config_xml = ""
@num = 0

if @lenght != 0
    ARGV.each_with_index do |a , x|

        @num = @num + 1
        b = ARGV[@num]

        if ((a == "-f") && !(b.match "-") )

            @factory_config_xml = b
            x += 1
            @num = @num + 1

        elsif ((a == "-x") && !(b.match "-") )

            @factory_config_xml = b
            x += 1
            @num = @num + 1

        elsif ((a == "-p") && !(b.match "-") )

            @factory_config_xml = b
            x += 1
            @num = @num + 1
        end

    end
end


puts @factory_config_xml
```

Comment: Why use instance variables everywhere? My eyes are bleeding...

Comment: Did you mean that you want to traverse your array jumping by 2 in each iteration? Please be specific about what you actually want.

Comment: it's not 2 every time. I am deciding jumping on run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel again, why don't you use an option parser library to parse your program arguments.

For example with [`OptionParser`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) your life would be much easier.

In this particular problem, incrementing the `x` variable by one won't help you, because in the next iteration `each_with_index` will pass the next integer again. So, you should create your own loop:

```
i = 0
while (i < ARGV.length) do
  # do your stuff with the incrementing but take care to increment in each loop
end
```